# What API is used to get information from /proc/pid/stat file?

Tags: c, linux, proc

what is the API to get fields from /proc/pid/stat instead of reading them ?

Comment: `open()`, `read()`, `close()` are sufficient, but you could also use `fopen()`, `fscanf()`, `fclose()`... In other words, it's just a (virtual) file...

Comment: I mean a syscall like sysinfo for example, there is no structure defined in C that gets those information ?